# How to update array stored in value of JavaScript Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, reduce

I am trying to use JavaScript's Map to store an array. The goal is to take an array of objects and group them by one of the object's keys ("last" in this example). Unfortunately, I keep getting the length of the array rather than the array itself stored and it later throws an error when calling .push().

The console logs:

```
[]
[]
[]
1
```

I get this error in the console:

*Uncaught TypeError: acc.get(...).push is not a function at ():15:45 at Array.reduce () at :10:27*

Here is my example:

```
let names = [
{first: "John", last: "Smith", age: 12}, 
{first: "Jessica", last: "Jones", age: 22}, 
{first: "Lois", last: "Lane", age: 32}, 
{first: "Joe", last: "Smith", age: 42}, 
{first: "Jenny", last: "Jones", age: 52}, 
{first: "Mary", last: "Smith", age: 62}
];

let grouppedArray = names.reduce(function(acc, cv) { 
    if (!acc.has(cv["last"])) {
        acc.set(cv["last"], []);
    }
    console.log(acc.get(cv["last"])); //this returns 1 when on the second smith
    acc.set(cv["last"], acc.get(cv["last"]).push(cv["last"]));
    return acc;
}, new Map());

console.log("grouppedArray", grouppedArray);
```

Comment: `push()` modifies the array in place, and returns the new length. You're storing this length into the map.

Comment: Don't call `acc.set()` when updating the array.

Comment: just `acc.get(cv.last).push(cv)` since its reference to same array it mutates no need to set

Comment: If you do a`console.log('acc:',acc,'cv:',cv);`you get the first one as `acc: {} cv: {
  "first": "John",
  "last": "Smith",
  "age": 12
}` so you see there is no array in either of those to push to.